# About the squares in square packing problem with 11 squares

Tags: calculus, packing-problem

In [this web site](https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/squinsqu/) there are the solutions of a lot of packing squares problems.
I know a very simple method to calculate with pen and paper the solution for the ten squares in a square using the same method than for five squares.

But now I try the eleven squares and the problem seems to be difficult, I try some approximations but they were not very conclusive. So I made a "puzzle" with eleven piece of paper and tried some configurations but they were not really interesting.

So I searched online but I find nothing about Walter Trump's method and I don't want to buy a book for $40 just to know the solution.

Have you got some ideas which can help me ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you trying to calculate $s$ or to prove $s$ is optimal?

Comment: I'm trying the both ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like there is [no proof](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=ElSi5V5uS2MC&pg=PA105&lpg=PA105&dq=Walter%20Trump%20square%20packing&source=bl&ots=_obV1R55Qz&sig=ZoZQLiwL_v0z8b7qdgabO2yIrbg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=WfhuVYiMG4a2swH8sYCYCg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Walter%20Trump%20square%20packing&f=false)$^1$ that this result is actually optimal. There also seems to be an unpublished proof that no $45^\circ$ solution is better than that of Trump, but the actual optimality proof is still out there.

The attached reference also gives a hint to finding the angle ($40.182^\circ$) and configuration:

[image]

1. "Which Way Did the Bicycle Go?: And Other Intriguing Mathematical Mysteries", pp. 105

Comment: Is it difficult to find these two equations ? :)

Comment: @Shadock - difficult? no. tedious? very.

Comment: OK i will try and if I don't find them you will give me :P Thank you for your help !